# Is ST-TCDMMAM dock compatible with Macbook pro M1 2021?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, dock, compatibility

I just got a Macbook Pro M1 2021 model and I am looking for a compatible dock for it.

I have found [this](https://satechi.net/products/type-c-dual-multimedia-adapter?variant=29646048460888) product but before ordering it I would like to know if its compatible with the specific laptop.

On the official Satechi website about **dual USB Type-C version**, it states `Dual display not supported on Apple M1 Macs. 2020/2019/2018 MacBook Pro, 2020/2018 MacBook Air, and 2020/2018 Mac Mini. Does not support MacBook models with a single USB-C port`

but I was surprised to see that the **single USB Type-C** version of this product is also stated as not compatible for my Mac (it made me think that the official website is maybe not updated). More specifically it says `MacBook Pro M2, MacBook Air M2, 2020/2019/2018/2017/2016 MacBook Pro, 2020/2018 MacBook Air, 2020/2018 iPad Pro, 2021 iMac M1, 2019/2017 iMac, iMac Pro, 2015/2016/2017 MacBook, Microsoft Surface Laptop 3/Surface Pro 7/Go, Google PixelBook Go, ChromeBook, Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro S, HP Spectre Convertible, Razer Blade, Huawei Matebook and more USB-C devices.`

I have not tried to contact the vendor (Satechi), but I posted it instead thinking that it might be interesting to more people. Please let me know if it makes sense to change the question title and make it more general.

The peripherals that I am interested in connecting are :

- USB 3.0 (at least 2)
- USB Type C (not very important, there are some spare ports on the Mac)
- HDMI for 1 4K@60Hz monitor
- Ethernet adapter (1Gb would be nice)
- SD card reader (nice to have)

Any information or product suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Find an Anker, Kramer or Belkin USB-C dock/hub that meets your needs. From years of research on docks/hubs and dongles, these three manufacturers have the most reliable and well-constructed devices. Also, for a more complete answer, please edit your question to provide what devices you intend to attach to the dock, including external drives. _Note: no financial or other consideration provided by the three companies mentioned above._

Comment: Did you contact the vendor about this, what was their reply? Which specific features do you need?

Comment: I've just rejected reopening this. As @nohillside says, you really need to contact the vendor about this, especially since their FAQs are confusing. You'll need to specify your Mac model and what you want to do, and you may want to point out they need to better clarify their FAQs (e.g. [1](https://support.satechi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052537092-Will-this-adapter-output-video-to-two-external-monitors-when-connected-to-the-new-Mac-lineup-with-M1-Processor-) v [2](https://support.satechi.com/hc/en-us/articles/7689261904283-Does-this-adapter-support-the-new-M2-MacBook-Pro-and-M2-MacBook-Air-)).